# Severe error on MERGE OUTPUT statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, etl

I'm getting a severe error - code 20, from a Merge statement and I am not sure why. The MERGE runs fine if I remove the OUTPUT $action clause, and updates/inserts the target table as expected. As soon as I put the OUTPUT clause in, either as a simple OUTPUT $action or storing it in a table variable and selecting from that, it causes an error level 20. I am using two CTEs for the target and source. Not sure if that's contributing to the issue, but as I said, it works fine without an OUTPUT clause. Using SQL Server 2008. I've removed most of the columns for readability here.

```
USE [DM]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MergeMDATEST]

@InsertAuditKey INT = 10
,@UpdateAuditKey INT = 1

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @RowCounts TABLE (mergeAction varchar(20));
--------------------------------------------
--- CTEs to add in Binary_Checksum Calcs ---
WITH SourceQuery AS
(
SELECT TOP 100
    [Company]
    ,[AccountNumber]
    ,BINARY_CHECKSUM([Company]) As [Checksum]
FROM #temptestMergeSource
)

,TargetTable AS
(
SELECT TOP 100
    [Company]
    ,BINARY_CHECKSUM([Company]) As [Checksum]
FROM #temptestMergeTarget
)

MERGE TargetTable AS Target
USING SourceQuery As Source
    ON (
        Target.[AccountIndex] = Source.[AccountIndex]
        AND Target.[CodeID] = Source.[CodeID]
        AND Target.[GroupID] = Source.[GroupID]
        )
WHEN MATCHED AND (Target.[Checksum] <> Source.[Checksum]) THEN 
    UPDATE SET
            [AccountNumber] = Source.[AccountNumber]
            ,[AuditKey] = @UpdateAuditKey

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (
            [Company]
            ,[AuditKey]
            )
    VALUES (
            Source.[Company]
            ,@InsertAuditKey
            )
OUTPUT $action INTO @RowCounts;

SELECT * FROM @RowCounts
-----RowCounts returned for auditing
--SELECT
--  COUNT(CASE WHEN mergeAction = 'Insert' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [INSERT] 
--  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN mergeAction = 'Update' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As [UPDATE]
--FROM @RowCounts
```

Comment: This seems like a bug in SQL Server [maybe related to this one](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/581548). I was also able to reproduce it on SQL Server 2012 (both 11.0.2376 and 11.0.3339), and without inserting into the @table variable. The problem goes away if you remove the OUTPUT clause altogether. You should contact Product Support.

Comment: Also, you should consider using traditional update/insert code paths instead of MERGE. In addition to this bug, there are many others that haven't been fixed. [I list some here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug) (scroll down) and [Alex K lists some here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14860/1186) (some may overlap).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll contact and see if we can shed some more light on this. Never would have written a merge with CTEs and source views had I known these issues existed!

Comment: CTE Target table with a calculated column! bah. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/788408/sql-server-2012-merge-with-cte-with-output-clause-msg-0-level-11-state-0-line-0

Comment: Voted and indicated that I can repro. You can probably self-answer that this is a bug and point to the Connect item you filed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A calculated column in a CTE Target combined with an output clause results in a fatal error. Bug submission on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/788408/sql-server-2012-merge-with-cte-with-output-clause-msg-0-level-11-state-0-line-0)

Comment: +1 - one more notch in my growing list of arguments against `MERGE`. :-)

Comment: Might be related to [this bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/581548), which is fixed for 2012 but unlikely to get back-ported to 2008/2008 R2 unless enough people call support with the issue (hint, hint).